# Laravel spatie/laravel-permissions

Tags: laravel

I need help with spatie/Laravel permissions . when i try to assign it gives me error
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
$role = new Role;
$n = count($request['permission_id']);

for($i=0; $i< $n ; $i++)
{
    $role->givePermissionTo('9');
}
```

Error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 761: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1048 Column 'role_id' cannot be null (SQL:
> insert into `role_has_permissions` (`permission_id`, `role_id`) values
> (9, ))

Comment: I'm not familiar with spatie but it looks like you need to save the role to DB before you can assign it to someone.

Comment: I have already saved some roles in DB

Comment: But you are creating a new role. `$role = new Role;` has nothing to do with already saved models. Not to mention your code doesn't make much sense. You are counting a number (X) you pass in the request, then you loop to give the unsaved role to user 9, X amount of times.

Comment: this what am trying to do    $role->givePermissionTo('POS' )

Comment: You're trying to add permission to an inexistent Role. Either create it `$role = Role::create(['name' => 'writer']);` or get it from your db : `$role = Role::where('name', 'writer')->first();`. Then you'll be able to give it permissions

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the role then you just need to get it like this:

```
$role = Role::find($id);
```

or (if you want to get it by the name)

```
$role = Role::where('name', '=' , $name)->get();
```

and then assign the permission

```
$role->givePermissionTo('name of the permission');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel when you create a model using `new` it is not inserted in to the database, you should `save` your model or use `create`

```
$role = new Role();
$role->save();  // role now has an id
```

or

```
$role = Role::create();  // new role and has an id
```

Also, your loop is not correct, did you mean to use the counter to index the array of permissions in the request? At the moment it will attempt to add the same permission as many times as there are items in the array.